# Apache www-data user not being able to execute .sh files through php shell_exec

Tags: php, bash, apache, shell-exec

I can run this command in the terminal

./rename_hostname.sh my_new_hostname

rename_hostname.sh consists of:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Assign existing hostname to $hostn
hostn=$(cat /etc/hostname)
newhost=$1

#change hostname in /etc/hosts & /etc/hostname
sudo sed -i "s/$hostn/$newhost/g" /etc/hosts
sudo sed -i "s/$hostn/$newhost/g" /etc/hostname

#display new hostname
sudo /etc/init.d/hostname.sh

echo "Successful"
```

And everything works fine.

But when I try to run this through PHP and Apache www-data

```
$exec = "/path/to/sh/rename_hostname.sh " . $new_hostname
$successful = shell_exec($exec);
```

It returns successful, but hostname doesn't get changed.

I have added in sudo visudo at the end of the file.

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/hostname.sh
www-data ALL = /etc/hosts
www-data ALL = /etc/hostname
```

And also tried

```
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/hosts
www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: /etc/hostname
```

Neither seem to help me out.

I also have chown the rename_hosname.sh to the www-data user

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Is selinux enabled/running? `getenforce` will help with this.

Comment: do you really need to mix php and bash? all that could be done purely in php

Comment: I tried using pure php for this, but same issue...I also have an error in the shell_exec above when typing in...it should be shell_exec("/path/to/sh/rename_hostname.sh new_hostname")

Comment: You may need to enable notty in the sudo config file.

Comment: I tried many things, including these suggestions above, however, I am able to do it giving entire root access to www-data user...but I can't seem to get /path/to/script working.  Ill try to enable notty and see what happens

Comment: I still have exactly the same problem, please do share if anyone can find the work around for this. I've tried many different combinations.